How can I track user engagement with files that are not hosted on a server using Google Analytics 4?
Is there a workaround to disable protocol checking in Google Analytics 4 for tracking user engagement in file-based applications like webOS apps, since GA4 no longer provides an option to disable it?

I tried Firebase Analytics, but it also requires hosted applications
I used Measurement Protocol, but it relies on client IDs auto-generated by Firebase Analytics or Google Analytics
I tried a hosted application, which works, but I'd prefer a non-hosted approach


Ok, so GA offers three essential approaches to tracking:

gtag.js for webapps tracking
firebase analytics sdk for native apps
MP for anything.

Your mistake is in your second point. MP does not rely on Firebase. The particular implementation of MP that you might have found somewhere on github may rely on Firebase, but that's quite an edge case since FB is perfectly capable of sending events with no explicit MP usage.
MP does require a client id, but you can generate it locally using whatever logic you see fit. It's up to you how you want to define and identify users.
